# How to rbind many xlsx files with start and end

Tags: r, xlsx, rbind

I have several files in one place. I merge them like this:

```
punkty_pgd <- read_xlsx("C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042500.xlsx", sheet = "NEW")
punkty_pgd_2 <- read_xlsx("C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042512.xlsx", sheet = "NEW")
punkty_pgd_3 <- read_xlsx("C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042600.xlsx", sheet = "NEW")
punkty_pgd <- rbind(punkty_pgd, punkty_pgd_2, punkty_pgd_3)
```

There are dates in their names and I would like to limit this merging somehow, that is, only merge files that have a date range in the name: from date_start to date_end

Comment: FYI, "merge" is not the right term for what you are doing with `rbind`: you are row-binding, row-concatenating, or just combining the frames. A "merge" operation is a "join", where you match one or more columns between frames, resulting in zero or more rows paired between them ... see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "load many files and process them", a good place to start is https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227.

Lacking that, let's address the filename/date thing.

First, assuming there are files you *don't* want to load (this time), then we should first get the names of the files.

```r
files <- list.files("c:/Users/Desktop", pattern = "\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)
### add a fake file without a date, for testing
files <- c(files, "Something.xlsx")

files
# [1] "C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042500.xlsx"
# [2] "C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042512.xlsx"
# [3] "C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042600.xlsx"
# [4] "Something.xlsx"
```

Now we can determine what the `Date` is by parsing the filenames.

```r
files <- cbind(strcapture("\\b([0-9]{10})\\b", files, list(fn = "")), origfn = files)
files
#           fn                               origfn
# 1 2021042500 C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042500.xlsx
# 2 2021042512 C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042512.xlsx
# 3 2021042600 C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042600.xlsx
# 4       <NA>                       Something.xlsx
```

(`strcapture` returns a `data.frame`, and I'll keep it in there for convenience.)

```r
files$date <- as.Date(files$fn, format = "%Y%m%d%H")
files
#           fn                               origfn       date
# 1 2021042500 C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042500.xlsx 2021-04-25
# 2 2021042512 C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042512.xlsx 2021-04-25
# 3 2021042600 C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042600.xlsx 2021-04-26
# 4       <NA>                       Something.xlsx       <NA>
```

Now we can filter just the files we need for a specific date range.

- base R:

  ```r
  dates <- as.Date(c("2021-04-20", "2021-04-25"))
  loadthese <- subset(files, dates[1] <= date & date <= dates[2])
  loadthese
  #           fn                               origfn       date
  # 1 2021042500 C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042500.xlsx 2021-04-25
  # 2 2021042512 C:/Users/Desktop/PC- 2021042512.xlsx 2021-04-25
  list_of_frames <- lapply(loadthese$origfn, readxl::read_xlsx, sheet = "NEW")
  punkty_pgd <- do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)
  ```
- tidyverse

  ```r
  dates <- as.Date(c("2021-04-20", "2021-04-25"))
  punkty_pgd <- files %>%
    filter(between(date, dates[1], dates[2])) %>%
    pull(origfn) %>%
    map_dfr(~ read_xlsx(., sheet = "NEW"))
  ```

Comment: Thank you, the solution works.
I still have a question, is it possible to somehow limit the date range not to exceed seven days?
The dates will be variables.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand. The current contrived code in this answer assumes six days, so if you change the value of my `dates` variable, you have full control over the span of the limits. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the code.
Everything is fine, it works as I wanted.

Thank you for your help. :)